# Жизненный цикл components/subcomponents в dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger2

Прочитал много разных статей про `@scope`, `components`, `subcomponents`. И вроде все понятно, но нигде не рассказывается про их жизненный цикл. И в целом я немного запутался. Помогите, пожалуйста, прояснить.

К примеру, я создаю `subcomponent` с соответствующими модулями и использую в `Activity` или `Fragments`

```
public MyActivityComponent plusMyActivityComponent() {

   if (myActivityComponent == null) {
         // start lifecycle of myActivityComponent 
         myActivityComponent = appComponent.plusMyActivityComponent(new MyActivityModule());
   }

   return myActivityComponent;
}
```

Есть необходимость самому следить за жизненным циклом этого компонента или он будет доступен сборщику мусора после уничтожения соответствующего активити/фрагмента?

В каких-то примерах "зануливают" `subcomponent` при onDestroy().

```
public void clearMyActivityComponent() {
        // end lifecycle of myActivityComponent
        subComponent = null;
}
```

А где-то нет. 
Я так понимаю, что заданный `scope` это "локальный синглтон" и получается, что он сохраняется как `static` и это может приводить к утечкам памяти в Android, если самому его как минимум не "занулить".

Answer (score 2):

Компонент живет пока кто-то держит на него ссылку.

Зависимости с аннотацией scope создаются один раз для одного компонента, потом компонент держит их в поле класса (не статическом) и при вызове зависимости из одного и того же компонента вы получаете один и тот же инстанс, который соответственно будет уничтожен вместе с компонентом. Поэтому можно назвать эту зависимость локальным синглтоном, в рамках инстанса компонента.

Зависимости без аннотации создаются каждый раз при вызове и инжекте (фабричный метод).

Соответственно к примеру если Вы создаете компонент внутри активити в `onCreate`, то при каждом повороте экрана у Вас будет новый компонент с новыми локальными синглтонами и не будет никакой утечки. Предыдущий компонент будет уничтожен GC вместе с активити (если конечно вы не передадите явные или неявные сильные ссылки на него объектам, которые будут живы при уничтожении активити).